# Python3 byte value written to Postgres string field. How to recover the value back?

Tags: python, postgresql, byte

So I had python byte values like: `b'"1aea43b1-b8a2-4d9b-917b-6fa982085b98"'.`

I wrote it to postgres' string field using `SQLAlchemy`. Now the value I see is something like this:
`\\x2262633134363235662d313662622d343230642d396434642d61383634613161393266346622`

How can I get the old value back?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of PostgreSQL:

```
select encode('\x2262633134363235662d313662622d343230642d396434642d61383634613161393266346622', 'escape');

                 encode
----------------------------------------
 "bc14625f-16bb-420d-9d4d-a864a1a92f4f"
(1 row)
```

Inside of Python:

```
>>> print(bytes.fromhex('2262633134363235662d313662622d343230642d396434642d61383634613161393266346622'))
b'"bc14625f-16bb-420d-9d4d-a864a1a92f4f"'
```